# How can I get views and unique views from a database table that has only user id and video id in one query?

Tags: sql, unique, compound-key

Say I have a table with columns `userId` and `videoId`, representing which user watched which video in a video app. Now I want to get the view count and the unique view count from the table, but using only **one** query. Is this possible? Here's a visual of the example:

[image]

Comment: Using the example image provided can you tell us what your desired output would be?  I'm not clear as to what you want the end result to be.

Comment: @BShaps the desired output is the table on the right of the image. A column for the video id, the number of views it has, and the number of unique views it has. The views and unique views would come from the users that watched the video.

Comment: how is this not possible? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AskYous Oh wow, helps if I actually read what you wrote above the tables, my bad.  When you say one query does that rule out unions and subqueries?

Comment: Nevermind. I just figured it out! I did `SELECT videoId, count(userId), COUNT(DISTINCT userId) FROM userstat GROUP BY videoId`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. I ran the following query:

```
SELECT 
    video, 
    count(user) AS views, 
    count( DISTINCT user) AS uniqueViews 
FROM <table>
GROUP BY videoId
```